# Copying strings of equal length to new string array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a dictionary of words stored in a 2D char array. I also have a scanned word stored in a structure. I'm trying to 'thin down' my main dictionary by copying words of length equal to the scanned word into a seperate 2D array. Then I want to print the new array out.

i.e if scanned word = `hello`, all words of the same length will be copied into the new array.

My code just prints the first word of the array infinitely

`words.startword` is the scanned word.

```
void get_equal_length (char equal_length_dictionary[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH], char dictionary[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH], Scanned_words words)

{
int i, word_count = 0;

for (i = 0; dictionary[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (strlen(*dictionary) == strlen(words.startword))
            {
                strcpy(*equal_length_dictionary, *dictionary);
                word_count++;
                printf("Word #%d: %s\n", word_count, *equal_length_dictionary);
            }
    }
    printf("Equal length words: %d\n", word_count);
}
```

Comment: What are your compiler flags? You should be getting a warning/error on `dictionary[i] != '\0'`, comparing a `char*` to a `char`

Comment: gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic "program.c"

Comment: Also you never use `i` in your loop, which should be a hint to the solution

Comment: Weird that that comparison doesn't throw an error. `dictionary[i] != '\0'` has no error but `char c = dictionary[i];` does. `warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast`

Comment: @Kevin The compiler won't complain about `dictionary[i] != '\0'`, because character literals are ints, so `'\0'` is just the integer zero, which is a valid pointer, i.e. NULL. It is true however that the condition in that `for` loop is totally wrong.

Comment: Oh good call. I didn't expect it to treat them the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> for (i = 0; dictionary[i] != '\0'; i++)
> {
>     if (strlen(dictionary) == strlen(words.startword))
>     {
>        strcpy(*equal_length_dictionary, *dictionary);
> ```

should be:

```
for (i = 0; dictionary[i][0] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (strlen(dictionary[i]) == strlen(words.startword))
    {
      strcpy(equal_length_dictionary[i], dictionary[i]);
```

Also, to improve speed, better calculate strlen(words.startword) only once before the loop, instead of recalculating it inside the loop at each iteration. You should also not forget to terminate the new array with a null string.

The full code will be:

```
void get_equal_length(char equal_length_dictionary[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH], char dictionary[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH], Scanned_words words)
{
  int i, word_count = 0, len = strlen(words.startword);

  for (i = 0; dictionary[i][0] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (strlen(dictionary[i]) == len)
    {
      strcpy(equal_length_dictionary[i], dictionary[i]);
      word_count++;
      printf("Word #%d: %s\n", word_count, equal_length_dictionary[i]);
    }
  }
  // now we will also terminate the new array with a null string
  equal_length_dictionary[i][0] = '\0';
  printf("Equal length words: %d\n", word_count);
}
```

Comment: For some reason this seg faults? :/

Comment: Does your dictionary array end with an empty string? If not this will keep trying to read past the end of the array

Comment: @Finlandia_C see the Edit plz. In fact you terminate your array of strings with a null string. To check if at index i you have a null string, use the edited checking. Also after the loop, dont forget to add a null string to your new array. Tell me if you have difficulties doing that :)

Comment: Ah yes this doesn't seg fault but only prints one word, the first equal length word of the array

Comment: The reason it's seg-faulting is dictionary[i] will never be equal to '\0'. You need to loop through the size of your dictionary, or have your loop test for  `dictionary[i][0]=='\0'`, assuming the words have all been nulled out.

Comment: @Finlandia_C I wrote the full code of the function to integrate all those corrections. See the code at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: I hate to say it is still just printing the first equal length word :/

Comment: Weird. Are you sure that you tested the full edited code, and that your parameter array `dictionary` is correct, that is, *has many words that match the criteria and does not have any empty string except the last one*?

Comment: @Finlandia_C you have a bug somewhere else in your code then; this part of the code is correct now

Comment: @A.S.H modern compilers will perform the optimization of hoisting the same `strlen` call out of the loop... micro-optimization is the least of OP's worries at the moment

Comment: Well I will look elsewhere in the code. You were very helpful though :)

Comment: @M.M thanks for the remark. True, this micro-optimization was not essential, just me too sensitive to this kind of programming patterns :p

Comment: Dictionary is read from a text file which is `word\n` etc, using fscanf, if I print dictionary is contains 5 words all of length 4, and the word scanned in is also length 4

Comment: @Finlandia_C plz post your test code so I can check it. Please make it a MC (Minimal and Complete) ;)

Comment: As I expected, you are not correctly reading the input file. Check this line: `while (fscanf(file_name, "%s", *dictionary) == 1)` ... this will only overwrite the first element of the array.

Comment: Ahhhh what should it be instead?

Comment: Try Change it into: `while (fscanf(file_name, "%s", dictionary[word_count]) == 1)`

Comment: You have gone over and above the requirement here!! thank you so much friend.

Comment: And at the end, after the loop, add an empty string: `dictionary[word_count][0] = '\0'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94754/discussion-between-finlandia-c-and-a-s-h).

Answer (score 0):

This should work, although not tested. As Kevin mentioned in the comment, you need to use the index i in the loop. You also should use word_count as index:

```
void get_equal_length (char equal_length_dictionary[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH], char dictionary[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH], Scanned_words words)

{
int i, word_count = 0;

for (i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS; i++)
    {
        char* cur_word = dictionary[i];
        if (!cur_word || !*cur_word)
          break;
        if (strlen(cur_word) == strlen(words.startword))
            {
                strcpy(equal_length_dictionary[word_count], cur_word);
                word_count++;
                printf("Word #%d: %s\n", word_count, equal_length_dictionary[word_count]);
            }
    }
    printf("Equal length words: %d\n", word_count);
}
```